# Won't come back from suspend 16.04 LTS

Tags: suspend, lenovo, hibernate, 16.04

There used to be a workaround with enabling suspending and hibernation, which worked for me at 14.04 LTS, but having cleanly installed 16.04 LTS I lost that, and now my computer won't come back from suspend.

I tried the tutorial listed here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/ to enable hibernation but running

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

Leaves me with black screen and processor running, I cannot restore the system, I can only manually shut it down and run again.

Yet my SWAP is bigger than my RAM (8.5 GB).

So I cannot hibernate nor suspend (the latter I can, but the computer doesn't wake up until restarted).

Please help?

Using Lenovo z50-71, i5 laptop with ATI /Intel hybrid graphics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had similar issue with not waking up after suspending, leaving me with black screen and processor running. There seems to be a bug in linux kernel that Ubuntu 16.04LTS is using. So upgrading the kernel to 4.4.8 solves the problem.

You can download the kernel for your system from [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.8-wily/) and set up.

Hopefully that solves your issue.

Comment: It actually did, upgrading to varios other LT and mainline kernels. Not the 4.4.0.22 build though. THanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/763516/51672):

## Use TuxOnIce kernel with uswsup for suspending

1. Double check if your swap partition/file is setup correctly in `/etc/default/grub`; you can do so by checking the location with either `cat /proc/swaps` or `swapon -s`; or you could better yet, find out the UUID or label of the swap partition/files(s) and use that:

   ```sh
   tail -n -9 /proc/swaps | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs sudo blkid
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub` by finding the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, add your swap partition inside, and save. If you use the UUID, prefix it with `UUID=` or `/dev/by-uuid/`.
3. Add the [TuxOnIce stable repository](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

   ```sh
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tuxonice/ppa
   ```
4. Install TuxOnIce kernel & uswsup:

   ```sh
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install uswsusp linux-generic-tuxonice tuxonice-userui
   ```
5. Restart your computer (`reboot;`)

Comment: Sorry about that @DavidFoerster , I have fixed the answer.

Comment: sudo apt install uswsup linux-generic-tuxonice tuxonice-userui

E: Unable to locate package uswsup

Comment: @CrazySynthax it was because I forgot an "s" in the uswsusp package name.