# Why isn't Hibernate in Ubuntu 16.04 working and how to fix it?

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, hibernate, 16.04

I have Kubuntu 16.04 64-bit installed on my HP Pavilion 17-f000 Notebook. I've tried the steps from the [ubuntu 16.04 wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html), but the `sudo pm-hibernate` terminal command did nothing and creating the `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` file with these contents also had had no effect:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower] Identity=unix-user:* Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate ResultActive=yes
[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind] Identity=unix-user:* Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions ResultActive=yes
```

I have 5.8GiB ram, 7.5GiB swap partition, and suspending to ram works fine.

Comment: How large is the swap partition. Suspend to disk, aka hibernation, doesn't work if swap size is less then RAM.

Comment: My swap partition is 7.5 GiB and my ram is 5.8 GiB.

Comment: Adding resume=/dev/myswapdevice to my /etc/default/grub and running `sudo update-grub`

Comment: does not help.
I didn't notice I didn't complete my previous comment.

Comment: As regards the piece of docs you linked to (which is part of the official documentation), it's out of date and will be updated in a few weeks. Please see https://launchpad.net/bugs/1575466

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably due to changes & regressions introduced in the 4.4.0 kernel [such as this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302) with Ubuntu 16.04, but I do have a workaround for 4.4.0:

I first added my swap partition to grub, rebooted, and there was no change. Next I installed the Ubuntu kernel packages with TuxOnIce stable and the option to hibernate appeared, but that failed. I later I installed the package `hibernate` which uses `uswsusp` for suspending to disk & ram and that worked. Below are the exact steps to achieve this:

1. Double check if your swap partition/file(s) are setup correctly in `/etc/default/grub`; you can do so by checking the location with either `cat /proc/swaps` or `swapon -s`.

   Better yet, find out the UUID or label of the swap partition/files(s) and use that:

   ```sh
   tail -n -9 /proc/swaps | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs sudo blkid
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/default/grub` by finding the line with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, add your swap device(s), and save. To enter the UUID, prefix it with `UUID=` or `/dev/by-uuid/`.
3. Save changes to GRUB:

   ```sh
   sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Add the [TuxOnIce stable repository](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

   ```sh
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tuxonice/ppa
   ```
5. Install TuxOnIce kernel & uswsup:

   ```sh
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install uswsusp linux-generic-tuxonice tuxonice-userui
   ```
6. Restart your computer (`sudo reboot;`)

Comment: Hey, I am able to hibernate my system using ' sudo pm-hibernate ', but there is no option to hibernate(on click upon top-right settings icon).

Comment: @NikhilVerma try this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/462480/51672

Comment: So by "add your swap device" you mean  add "resume=/dev/yourswap" ?

Comment: What exactly is meant by "add your swap device(s), and save. "?

Comment: Swap devices are designated areas the OS uses to swap out memory stored in RAM to your hard drive. You need to add those to the /etc/default/grub file, so when you come back from hibernating, GRUB will know where to look, in order to move it back to the RAM to resume your session.

Comment: @Alex According to this (https://askubuntu.com/a/196365/187411) it means to append the string `resume=UUID=[your UUID]` to the string that is already there. 
For example `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=549ae7468"`

Comment: @ossbuntu I followed all the steps. When I do: `tail -n -9 /proc/swaps | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs sudo blkid` it results: `/dev/sda9: UUID="446fad30-4abb-4b70-91b0-0e09059e0a14" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="150f68f3-b6a2-48c9-825a-5cac06e1225d"`. So,  I finally make the change in `/etc/default/grub` like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=446fad30-4abb-4b70-91b0-0e09059e0a14"`.  After all these I run in terminal: `sudo pm-hibernate` and system goes to hibernate. When i press power button I select ubuntu and black screen appears and system does not goes to login screen. any fix?

Comment: @LearningROR I don't know... but I included the `quiet splash` words in my **example** just because they were there beforehand for my computer. Maybe `quiet splash` doesn't work for your computer, I honestly don't know what they mean or what they do, but you should only include whatever words were there beforehand and add the `resume=[UUID]` part

Comment: @ossbuntu ahh ok. No problem. I tried all possible options but nothing seems to work for me. :) I am using Dell Inspiron 5558

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem in Ubuntu 16.04, and nothing seemed to help.

I finally figured out that I just had to **disable Secure Boot** in the BIOS menu. I had already done the steps suggested in the accepted answer, so I can't say whether they were necessary in my case.