# Pm-hibernate - doesn't work, or create log file

Tags: 16.04, power-management, hibernate

Preliminary 
ubuntu 16.04
dual boot on a disk that also runs windows 10
hibernate works in windows 10
swap partition is the same size as RAM

Problem
When I run sudo pm-hibernate from the terminal nothing happens. The line advances as though the command has been run but there's no action. If i try to check the log in /var/log/ there's no file for pm-hibernate. However there is a log for pm-suspend.

i've checked the pm-suspend file but it is not recording any information when i try to hibernate. the pm-suspend file gets updated when i run sudo pm-suspend from the terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate ?? http://askubuntu.com/questions/761394/why-isnt-hibernate-in-ubuntu-16-04-working-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: Inspect `/var/log/pm*`, read the `man` page for, and run `pm-is-supported`

Comment: pm-is-supported shows that hibernate is supported, forgot to mention that

Comment: answer is duplicate, the link Mohamed provided helped

Comment: @waltinator `pm-is-supported --hibernate` has an empty output too. kek.

Comment: Read `man pm-is-supported`. `pm-is-supported` returns its answer in its exit status (`$?` in `bash`). Follow your `pm-is-supported --hibernate` command immediately with `echo $?` to se the status.