# Hibernate not working on xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, power-management, hibernate

Hey I have the same problem as [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/761394/587751) (`pm-hibernate` not doing anything and not producing a log file, hibernate option greyed out in every interface), except I'm on xubuntu, not sure if that makes any difference. I followed the steps described in the chosen answer, and it still doesn't work (also, `pm-is-supported --hibernate` does not seem to do anything either).

Maybe I misinterpreted how I was supposed to edit `/etc/default/grub`. Currently the corresponding line is set to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash UUID=da462d1a-465f-435a-acec-1689eeaca9a6"`

Comment: After changing the line in `/etc/default/grub`, did you issue the command `sudo update-grub`?  Just changing the line is not sufficient.

Comment: Yes I did, I even rebooted since then and still nothing new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I'm stupid, you have to boot the tuxOnIce kernel instead of the default one. Now `pm-hibernate`  works just fine.

One weird thing though, it doesn't seem to recover from hibernation (hangs on "loading initial ramdisk" for up to 2 minutes) if I don't use the tuxOnIce (upstart) option. Anyone knows why ?