# Laptop screen does not turn off automatically after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, xubuntu, power-management, lock-screen

I upgraded the Xubuntu on my Samsung laptop using the update utility and now the screen goes blank but does not turn off if I leave it idle on battery. I get the error "sleep verb not supported".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868208/how-to-activate-hibernation-in-16-04-1-systemd)

Comment: I'm not concerned with hibernation.

Comment: Where is the error "sleep verb not supported" coming from? logfile? command?

Comment: It shows in a "balloon" on top right of the screen when I press a key and the (blank) screen saver goes away.

Comment: Is secure boot enabled in the bios? What are the stats on "MEM" and "SWAP" when you run **top -n 1**

Comment: I have to check for the secure boot but here is the output of top.  KiB Mem :  8087848 total,  3578944 free,  2607692 used,  1901212 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  3124220 total,  3124220 free,        0 used.  4842824 avail Mem

Comment: Swap does not appear to be enabled - "0 used". Try **sudo swapon -a**

Comment: It's UUID was changed recently. I updated fstab and the corresponding line is now: UUID=887644a0-196a-4c34-9b73-373d93047cb0 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72303/discussion-between-stumblebee-and-reza).