# how to enable hibernate on ubuntu lenovo y50

Tags: hibernate

Hibernation worked flawlessly on Windows 10 just before I've switched to Ubuntu (16.04), so I know for sure that the laptop (Lenovo y50) supports it.

Here's some info about the system:

```
$ sudo systemctl hibernate
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15952        2953       11727         409        1271       12258
Swap:         16295           0       16295
$ cat /sys/power/state
freeze mem
$ ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/acpi
acpi_configfs.ko  acpi_ipmi.ko  apei  ec_sys.ko  sbshc.ko  video.ko
acpi_extlog.ko    acpi_pad.ko   dptf  nfit       sbs.ko
```

Tried the instructions of the [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html), editing the file with the right config:

`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

Also tried other locations, which I've found in other places on the internet:
`/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868208/how-to-activate-hibernation-in-16-04-1-systemd), disabling secure boot in the Bios setting seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Worked! Had to disable Secure Boot, as suggested in the link. Thanks!