# Can't hibernate on 18.04 on Lenovo T580

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, lenovo, hibernate

I've tried to search for how to enable hibernation on Ubuntu 18.04, but none of the suggested methods are working for me.

I have a Lenovo T580 ThinkPad with an SSD disk which is a dual-boot system with Windows 10.

```
$ sudo systemctl hibernate
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported
$ sudo pm-hibernate
sudo: pm-hibernate: Command not found
$ cat /sys/power/disk
[platform] shutdown reboot suspend test_resume 
$ sudo apt-get install pm-hibernate
Reading package lists... Done
Buidling dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pm-hibernate
```

My /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=d2d3c950-154c-4192-a4a2-496c884bf9dd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=8CD7-3389  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

And

```
$ swapon --show
NAME      TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file   2G   0B   -2
```

Any suggestions?

Best regards,
Steen

Comment: have you tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868208/how-to-activate-hibernation-in-16-04-1-systemd)

Comment: Thanks! I did read that, but that problem was that `cat /sys/power/disk` returned `[disabled]` and after disabling secure boot returned "normal" values. Mine already returns values suggesting hibernation is enabled...

Comment: another way to hibernate is to install `uswsusp` and afterwards hibernate with `sudo s2disk`. pls do you have a swap partition?

Comment: I suppose I have a swap partition - I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 with no custom partitioning other than I chose to install Ubuntu alongisde Windows. How do I see if I have a swap partition?

Comment: I don't have a swap partition; I don't even have a swap file. As far as I can see, I can only implement either by editing /etc/fstab, and I've promised myself to never do that again. So there's that. But thanks for your help :-)

Comment: By the way - I think it's a little strange that the default Ubuntu installation doesn't automatically make a swap partition. Oh well.

Comment: can you kindly post the output of /etc/fstab. `sudo fdisk -l` and `swapon --show` can show swap partitions.

Comment: I've pasted the contents above.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file  looks like natively you won't be able to hibernate to swapfile unless you use uswsusp From the first error pm-hibernate needs to be installed with `sudo apt install pm-utils`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error on my X1 Carbon 7th Gen. 
I did the following to enable the hibernation (Detailed instructions are [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1197965/889735)):

1. Turn off Secure Boot in BIOS.
2. Turn off "Modern Standby" in BIOS.
3. Create a swap file bigger than my RAM.
4. Update the grub.

After the above steps, I can use `sudo systemctl hibernate` command to hibernate and resume properly.

Comment: is there any reason why secure boot has to be off? especially if running on a MOK?

Comment: Good point. I had the same question. I could not set it with Secure Boot enabled but I am not using MOK. Do you have hibernation with Secure Boot enabled?

Comment: I currently dont even have hibernation with secure boot (although I am using a kinda unorthodox file with a swapfile on an extra partition aside because the Linux partition is just way too small

but on reddit I did also ask and I read that apparently the kernel has no way to sign the hibernation image, and without that secure boot would be kinda pointless