# secure boot: verification of initramfs

Tags: secure-boot

according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot *Initrd images are not validated*. Is this information up to date? this would make the whole secure boot totally useless as an attacker could very easily replace initramfs with a one that logs LUKS password and sends it to him... This in turn would make all the module signing hassle and [disabling hibernation on secure boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/1125038/352473) totally ridiculous.

if it's indeed so, is there any launchpad bug/feature-request that we can upvote to make secure boot actually secure?

OTOH, if this statement is obsolete, how does the verification work? where is the key pair that is used to sign initrd files when they are generated during new kernel installations? which component later verifies the signature? (shim, MOK, GRUB, kernel itself?) ...or maybe PCRs and TPM are somehow used instead?
...and how about the kernel command line? this one must be signed/verified also to make the boot secure...

Comment: @snaker I somehow have a feeling that you may have some clue regarding this ;-)

Comment: The ability to *vote* on bug trackers is merely a tool to reduce *me too!*-style distractions. To get things adopted in the main Ubuntu repositories you should instead be demonstrating that the thing you want a) works and b) has some merit.

Answer (score 7):

According to my current understanding with regard to Ubuntu 20.04:

- shim is signed by Microsoft's key and contains a Canonical key. Microsoft's key is shipped preinstalled in EFI, and is used to validate shim
- grub is signed by Canonical's key and checked by shim
- kernel is signed by Canonical's key and checked by grub

There are 2 basic cases:

1. Attended boot

- you can encrypt your `/boot` partition (LUKS1 only, LUKS2 support is not there in Ubuntu 20.04. Newer Grub will support LUKS2 with some limitations (https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/docs/grub.texi#n4554)) or have a single system partition with `/` and `/boot` (LUKS1)
- Grub will ask for the password to unlock it and read kernel and `initrd` from it

  - Note: grub2 is known to be slow (10-20 seconds) to decrypt /boot: I could not find an official acknowledgement of the issue from grub team, but there are many threads on the matter, with workarounds: not using encrypted boot at all or having a key with lower iteration count in the first slot of luks header (ie: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=228865)
- this way the complete system integrity is protected implicitly by using disk encryption for `/boot` and `/`

2. Unattended boot

- you can't encrypt `/boot` in this case, so you have 2 choices
- sign `initrd` and kernel and force them to be checked:

  - either you can create an EFI binary with all stuff (kernel, `initrd`, `grub.cfg`) packed in it, sign with a custom key and add this key to the EFI key store
  - or do the same thing, but instead of putting everything into the Grub EFI binary, you only add a GPG public key there, which is the one you use to sign the `grub.cfg`, kernel and `initrd` (https://ruderich.org/simon/notes/secure-boot-with-grub-and-signed-linux-and-initrd)
  - in either case you'll have to generate signatures or even EFI binaries each time your `initrd` is updated (ideally automatically via `initramfs-tools` hooks)
- if you don't want to mess with signing and have TPM

  - you can leave `initrd` and `/boot` as is and let any attacker to modify it, but you bind your root fs to the appropriate TPM registers, effectively preventing access to the `rootfs` if anybody has altered kernel parameters, any used files (kernel binary, `initrd`, `grub.cfg`)...
  - the only drawback here is, that after `initrd`/kernel change, you'll have to do a reboot, manually unlock the disk and rebind the TPM bound key slot on LUKS to the new PCR register values and make sure, that during this reboot nobody altered any of the `/boot` content. Ideal solution would be if one could calculate the future TPM value and as such not have to keep luks TPM bound. A project which is addressing this issue:  https://github.com/grawity/tpm_futurepcr

Some further assorted references:

- https://www.scitepress.org/Papers/2021/103139/103139.pdf
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1854177
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Full_Disk_Encryption_Howto_2019
- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/configuring-automated-unlocking-of-encrypted-volumes-using-policy-based-decryption_security-hardening
- https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-enable-full-disk-encryption-on-an-ubuntu-20-04-desktop

Update: 2022-11-07: added some sources and details on grub2 limitations

Comment: This is a very good explanation. Can you provide some resources of these? I am interested in how to make this.

Comment: Your TPM answer is nice but if the attacker modifies the initramfs then the root will get unlocked anyway...

Comment: "if the attacker modifies the initramfs then the root will get unlocked anyway"

If the attacker modifies the initramfs boot will not happen due to the incorrect TPM register values to which your rootfs is bound. Depending on how you set up your system, you could have some fallback options (ie: type passphrase on console or over SSH), which of course you should do if and only if you've checked that your system have not tampered with.

Answer (score 2):

**You do not even need to sign/verify the *initramfs*, because you do not need to keep it accessible** (unenencrypted on a local disk).

Ubuntu `20.04` is perfectly capable of dealing with an installation layout where the initrd file is contained inside an encrypted container (currently works for *luks1* on AMD64 & ARM64, *luks2* and more platforms in future versions). Other than downgrading to the earliest version with identical kernel, nobody but you could modify the initrd sealed with your password.

The part that is really missing in current automation is the generation of a signed grub binary that verifies its own configuration. It works out of the box too - grub *can* verify gpg-style signatures - but the kernel install scripts shipped by *Canonical* do not setup/update that in the usual fully automatic fashion.

If you wanted to to configure a fully verified boot chain in current Ubuntu releases, you might try to place your own script (which `gpg --sign`s your config, then integrates that into the grub binary using `grub-mkstandalone` then `sbsign`s that binary before placing it into `/boot/efi`)  into `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/` to have it automatically called whenever your install/remove a kernel (version).

Note that almost no consumer PC is actually used to enroll custom keys for secure boot (*MOK*), so you will likely run into some firmware bugs. You will not find too many bug reports about this topic either, simply because few people want/do such a complicated and error-prone thing.

And this is just the Ubuntu side of things. You probably win *nothing* in terms of security (but you are [welcome to contribute there](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: does it mean in that in 20.04 displaying password prompt and actually unlocking luks device is handled by GRUB as opposed to scripts on initramfs as before?  (I'm on 18.04 still).  Thanks!

Comment: @morgwai no, that is just one of the possible setups that is correctly handled by the support scripts (initramfs-tools, grub) - it is *not* the default disk layout.

Comment: @anx When you put the initramfs an encrypted container this means there can not be any automated unlocking (for example with clevis/tag). Am I missing something?

Comment: @anx This problem with this approach is that you can not really automate it. If GRUB2 would support TPM unlocking then the whole problem would go away (as GRUB2 would unlock the partition containing the initramfs in a verified way and the bootloader EFI would be verified).

Comment: @FelixSchwarz You could create a unified kernel image (see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_kernel_image) (but it is not like it is very well supported with Ubuntu, maybe you can contact Canonical about this, they will surely think about it if people are asking for it :) ) and boot that if you need automated booting and unlocking. Also, you could look into encrypting and unlocking partitions via TPM2 (or some other U2F method (see: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Universal_2nd_Factor)).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to define a threat model first: what are you trying to protect against?

Secure Boot should prevent even the root user from breaking the integrity of code that runs at kernel-level privilege. This is most obvious at boot: even root should not be able to install a kernel or bootloader that isn't trustworthy, and we use signatures to determine trustworthiness. However, it also extends to the running kernel: Ubuntu kernels will detect secure-boot and enter lockdown integrity mode early in boot. Integrity mode attempts to maintain that security boundary between root and the kernel at runtime. (This stops you doing something like `kexec`-ing from a trusted kernel to an untrusted one.)

Something that has never been part of the secure boot mission is protecting against root replacing non-kernel binaries. This is a reasonably difficult problem and scripting languages make it even harder. It's even more fraught in the FOSS world because people get very irate at anything they perceive to be limiting software freedom, even if it's possible to disable. (See, for example, what Apple does with signing basically everything!)

There are definitely ways to restrict root installing malicious binaries. You can use grub's detached signature support to require that the initrd is signed. But then everything, even `grub.cfg`, has to be signed, and that would get really irritating to administer. You could use something like `dm-verity`. IMA could help you (but not so much for scripts). But you very quickly stop having a general purpose system!

Comment: > has never been part of the secure boot mission is protecting against root replacing non-kernel binaries. Why can't then root change PK/KEK/db? SB *does* protect boot process from malicious root (think about privilege escalation) by requiring that someone be physically present during boot, who could approve the changes of the EFI variables.