# Chrome Shuts Down on Hibernate Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, google-chrome, hibernate

I just recently installed ubuntu 22.04 and enabled hibernate by using swap partition. I enabled the hibernation by adding the swap partition UUID to the grub file `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=4a59c6a7-ca54-4e24-a362-3eac83bfe226 resume_offset=4974592".`

I always hibernate by running the command `sudo systemctl hibernate`

The problem is whenever I hibernate and resume all the files and apps that I left open will be open as expected, except google chrome which shuts down completely and I have to launch the app again

Please what can I do to resolve this. am a newb

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to disable UEFI secure boot and after that everything works.

You can usually enter the boot menu when your computer starts by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd>. From there, you look for *Secure Boot* and then disable it.

I found this short documentation from Gigabyte: [How to disable Secure Boot in BIOS](https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Support/FAQ/3001).

There is also a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106105) with more information and alternative solutions.

Comment: Disabling UEFI is a bad habbit!

Comment: @KjeldFlarup This is no "habit" - I only did it once and I would not know about any reason to disable secure boot so often as to form a habit. I have also linked a more detailed response and discussions. If you find a good solution, feel free to post it as an answer. I would be happy to re-enable secure boot, but at the moment it is more important for me not to lose my work on every hibernate.