# How to enable 'systemctl hibernate' without turning off SecureBoot?

Tags: 18.04, uefi, hibernate

[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/868208/11316) and other questions/answers around the web recommend turning off SecureBoot to get `systemctl hibernate` to work when encountering the error:

```
Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported
```

How can I get `systemctl hibernate` to work as designed (i.e. hibernate/suspend-to-disk) **without disabling SecureBoot**?

NB: I'd like to avoid `pm-utils` unless absolutely necessary. SystemD appears to be the way to do it and there are lots of suggestions that `pm-utils` doesn't work well together with SystemD.

Comment: I think there is no way to use hibernation with SecureBoot enabled, unless you recompile a kernel. Why do you need SecureBoot? It is completely useless.

Comment: @Pilot6 I wonder why the site search _and_ the link suggestions didn't bring this up while I wrote my question. I also voted to close as dupe. Thanks for bringing my attention to the already answered question.

Comment: You can close  it as dupe instead of voting because it's your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 surprisingly I could not. When I clicked `close` the only thing it offered me was to vote just as you (?) did before me. Probably a matter of reputation/privileges.

Comment: You should have a link on top where you agree that this is a dupe. I can test it but I saw one.

Comment: @Pilot6 seriously, I don't. When I clicked the `close` link I could choose "duplicate of ...", which I did and then I was prompted to pick a duplicate (which was the one you evidently linked). During the whole process I was never given the option to close the question myself. I don't know, perhaps this is different if no one else has voted to close the question before, but I am not given any option here to close it. The only alternative would be deletion. And I do not like that option because I must have used terminology different enough for suggestions to fail. So dupe is better.

Comment: @Pilot6 I came across my question again and now it worked to close as a dupe.