# Failed to suspend system via logind: Sleep verb not supported (16.04)

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management

After switching from MBR to GPT and updating `grub` (possibly overwriting my previous configuration, possibly unrelated, but that would be a strange coincidence) on my desktop computer I can no longer suspend my system (Ubuntu 16.04.7).

I first noticed that the "suspend" menu item is gone, and trying from the command line, `sudo systemctl suspend` returns `Failed to suspend system via logind: Sleep verb not supported`. `pm-suspend` does not do anything, `pm-is-supported --suspend ; echo $?` returns `1` (i.e. not supported).

As suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/870528/75050), I checked the contents of `/sys/power/disk`. It reads `[shutdown] reboot suspend` so the solutions from there don't seem to apply here. (I also haven't found a secure boot option in my BIOS/UEFI settings but may have missed that.)

How can I fix this? It definitely used to work before.

Comment: Is this answer helpful? https://askubuntu.com/questions/868208/how-to-activate-hibernation-in-16-04-1-systemd

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that: I had checked that, but no. Will edit.

Comment: `cat /sys/power/state` please.

Comment: `cat /sys/power/state`: `disk`

Comment: I miss entry `freeze`.  Please look again in your uefi for option secure boot. If bios mode was running, I really  think that secure boot is causing this.

Comment: I had to update the BIOS because the old version did not show the secure boot setting. Now it says that secure boot is disable (no option to change it though) but `cat /sys/power/state` still gives the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had another look at the `grub` configuration and found

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

had somehow made its way back into `/etc/default/grub`. After removing the `acpi=off` setting, `sudo update-grub`, and rebooting, the suspend option is back and works.

(Unrelated to this particular problem but probably useful in general for this type of problem is [this guide on "Best practice to debug Linux* suspend/hibernate issues"](https://01.org/blogs/rzhang/2015/best-practice-debug-linux-suspend/hibernate-issues).)